# SQL and IIS HDDs configuration on server

Tags: sql-server, hard-drive

I've just added a new production server and I was wondering if you guys could help me decide which configuration suits best.

Current configuration:

- 40GB ~ C (System)
- 250GB ~ D (SQL - MDF & LDF)
- 250GB ~ F (IIS)
- 1TB ~ E (storage of users' files)
- (note: C and D are partitions on the same physical HDD)

I've heard splitting LDF/MDF can do magic in terms of performance. Therefore, the core of my question is how would you recommend to do so. For example, putting the MDF with the IIS is an option, yet I'm not so sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

> I've heard splitting LDF/MDF can do
>   magic in terms of performance.

Yes. When they are on SEPARATE DRIVES. You dont split anything. Gain: zero.

I would combine F and E - IIS does not use so much (only logging). C for System, D for LDF, F for SQL.

That said, obviously all discs mirrored with a proper raid controller, bbu cache and... high performance discs.